# laravel con visual code, no funciona comandos

Tags: laravel, composer

formatee mi equipo de trabajo, ya tenia proyectos hechos y los abro con visual code tengo extenciones, las cuales son:
laravel blade snippets.
laravel artisan.
laravel 5 snippets.
laravel goto wiew.
laravel blade.

al crear un proyecto nuevo composer create-project laravel\laravel Nombre_proyecto.

u otro comando php artisan migrate.
dice que o son reconocidos.
error:

u el termino php no se reconoce...

**composer : El término 'composer' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- composer create-project laravel\laravel Nombre_proyecto
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (composer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**.
  ```

ese error me dice.
necesito su ayuda.

Comment: Que tal, ya descargaste y configuraste correctamente [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)?

Comment: si, lo solucione con otra respuesta de este foro

Comment: El error no tiene que ver con Visual si no con la estructura de tu comando

Comment: @LuisFelipeBarrosBustos recuerda agregar esa respuesta a tu pregunta para que no quede abierta, aunque creo que es mejor que lo elimines ya que el mismo error te dice la solucion